# Inserir um video do youtube numa pagina html

Tags: html, html5, youtube

Gostaria de inserir um video em uma pagina web, mas não consigo. Qual é o problema que contém neste código?

```
<object width="425" height="344">

    <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBjjnqG0BP8"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<!-- copiado -->
  <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBjjnqG0BP8" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344">
  </embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com este código é possível inserir um vídeo em sua pagina HTML:

```
<iframe width="X" height="Y" src=http://www.enderecodovideo.com frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Você precisa pegar o endereço EMBED no Youtube http://imageshack.com/a/img537/6295/refUy4.png 
Onde está X e Y você preenche com o tamanho adequado.